# How to extract bare filenames from a list of file paths using regexes

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

So, my archive manager seems not to have preserved the directory hierarchy when extracting a tar.xz file. Now my Downloads folder is messy and full of files not in their proper places.

I want to delete those and only those files that were in the archive to start with. To do this I am trying to match the ends of each file path from the output of `tar tf file.tar.xz` and delete the associated files.

For example if the input is:

```
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/firefox.real
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/fonts/
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/fonts/Arimo-Bold.ttf
```

I want the output to be:

```
firefox
firefox.real
Arimo-Bold.ttf
```

so I can delete them.

I have been trying to accomplish this with `sed 's/.*\/([^\/]+)$/\1/'` but that gives the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS` and I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/\/$/d; s|.*/||'
```

`/\/$/d` removes any line with trailing `/`. `s|.*/||` removes everything before the last `/` (if any) and the `/` itself.